# how to configure gitlab-runner with conan remote?

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner, conan

I'm trying to setup conan for a gitlab-runner.

When I configure conan for myself, I can use "conan remote add...", "conan user..." and the results are saved in my home directory.

However, I can't login as gitlab-runner, so I don't know how to make those settings persist.  I can define CONAN_USER_HOME in .gitlab-ci.yml to point to a directory, but it's not clear that gitlab-runner will have the permissions to read anything I add to that directory.

Is this typically done by adding those conan commands to .gitlab-ci.yml so they are invoked for every run?  That feels like a waste of resources.

Answer (score 1):

Conan provides some environment variables which helps you to login according your remote name: [CONAN_LOGIN_USERNAME_](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/env_vars.html#conan-login-username-conan-login-username-remote-name) and [CONAN_LOGIN_PASSWORD_](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/env_vars.html#conan-password-conan-password-remote-name).

However it does not solve your problem completely, you need to add your remote address. So that, you can use Gitlab env vars to be dynamic:

```
image: conanio/gcc8:latest

run:
  script:
    - conan remote add upload_repo ${CONAN_REMOTE}
    - conan create . demo/stable
    - conan upload foo/0.1.0@demo/stable --all -r upload_repo
```

Here I just add my Conan repository by the env var `${CONAN_REMOTE}` which will be configured through my Gitlab env vars. Also, I should have `CONAN_LOGIN_USERNAME_upload_repo` and `CONAN_LOGIN_PASSWORD_upload_repo`, otherwise I would need an extra step for `conan user -r upload_repo -p <password> <username>`

It works for simple build, but I would say it is limited and don't scale well when you need to build different configurations.

IMO you should try [Conan Package Tools](https://github.com/conan-io/conan-package-tools) which is an extension to be used on CI. You can generate a template for gitlab, running:

`conan new foo/0.1 -cis -ciglg`

It will generate the files `build.py` and `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

Also, you can take a look on this [example](https://gitlab.com/uilianries/conan-example/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml) using Gitlab.

Comment: Here's what happens if I specify CONAN_USER_HOME=/scratch1/conan2 and try to have Conan create the cache in .gitlab-ci.yml: `conan user -r my-repo build_bot`  
WARN: Remotes registry file missing, creating default one in /scratch1/conan2/.conan/remotes.json  
ERROR: No remote 'my-repo' defined in remotes

Comment: I think your problem is Gitlab and not Conan. Conan is following the correct steps, as your Conan user home is empty, it will create a new one there.

Comment: Keeping Conan packages cached by Gitlab is not a good practice. I could upload packages to a local remote and download it again when building.

Answer (score 0):

Conan seems [better integrated](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/conan_repository/) with GitLab through, as an alternative approach, a [package registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/).

And with [GitLab 14.6](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/12/22/gitlab-14-6-released/#publish-conan-packages-with-only-name-and-version) (December 2021), you even can:

> ### Publish Conan packages with only name and version
>
> You use the GitLab Conan repository to publish and share your C/C++ packages. >
> When creating a Conan package, there are four fields to consider: `name`, `version`, `user`, and `channel`.
> These fields uniquely identify a package. The `user` and `channel` fields are optional in [Conan 2.0](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/conan_v2.html), but GitLab required you to continue using them.
>
> Customizing your naming conventions to match the requirements in GitLab instead of the standards set by Conan is inefficient and impractical.
>
> We’ve updated the GitLab Conan repository to align with Conan.
> Now you can publish and download your Conan packages with or without the `user` and `channel` fields.
>
> This improvement helps you to be more efficient and makes it easier to find and validate packages in the user interface. This change is the first step in a broader set of [planned improvements](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/6816) to the Conan repository to help move the feature from Beta to GA.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/conan_repository/#package-without-a-username-and-a-channel) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/345055).